# How to register a model binder in web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to register a custom model binder in Web Api, but can't seem to find the correct way to do it.

> System.ArgumentException: 'The service type SimpleModelBinderProvider is not supported.'

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.ModelBinding;

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...

        var provider = new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(CustomerIdentity), new CustomerIdentityModelBinder());
        config.Services.Insert(typeof(SimpleModelBinderProvider), 0, provider);

        ...
    }
}
```

I've tried `SimpleModelBinderProvider` and `ModelBinderProvider`.

**What is the proper way to register a custom model binder in web api?**

*NOTE: I'm not using the `ModelBinderAttribute` on the class because it's in another assembly which would cause a circular-dependency (and because I don't like decorating classes with attributes).*

*NOTE: Starting to think this might be namespace related. The project has both MVC5 and WebApi2 in it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Namespace Issue**

I should have been using the namespaces:

```
// In the WebApiConfig.
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders;

// For the ModelBinder itself.
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using System.Web.Http.ValueProviders;
```

Instead of:

```
using System.Web.ModelBinding;
```

The code was near identical as well as the class names, which is why it was hard to track down and figure out.